# Filling in blank months using objects from other months

Tags: python, django

I have a product list, and a connected price list for every product. I have imported some data to populate the price list for every month, but there are some month missing, and I would like to populate the missing months using the saved months based on `published_from` and `published_to`

My models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  
    product_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)



class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.FloatField()
    date_saved = models.DateTimeField()
    published_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    published_to = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is what I have tried, but I don't get any errors, and there are not created any new prices.

```
def fill_in_blanks_prices(request):

    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    month_list = [[datetime(2014, i, 1)] for i in xrange(1, 13)]


    #Loop through every product  
    for product in product_list:

        #Loop through every month
        for month in month_list:

            #Month returns a list with one datetime object
            for item in month:
                naive = item
                current_month = pytz.timezone("Europe/Oslo").localize(naive, is_dst=None)

                try:
                    price = Price.objects.filter(product=product, date_saved=current_month)
                    #Price found, do nothing
                    pass

                 except Price.DoesNotExist:
                    #Price in the given month not found
                    #Find a price that is published_from greater than current month and published_to less than current month

                    try:
                        other_price = Price.objects.filter(product=product, published_from__gte=current_month, published_to__lte=current_month)[:1]

                        #Duplicate the other_price
                        for object in other_price:
                            object.id = None
                            object.date_saved__month = current_month
                            object.save()

                    except Price.DoesNotExist:
                        #No matching price
                        pass

    return HttpResponse("Processing")
```

Anyone see what Im doing wrong?

## Edit:

I found the error:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Price.date_saved received a naive datetime (2014-12-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
```

## Edit 2:

Im converting the datetime to not naive, but I still can't create new prices.

Comment: Can you try logging the values you are using/accessing in your 3rd For loop? Everything, may be there is something that is not what you are expecting it to be?

Comment: Thank you! I found the error now.